# SSAS Tabular Model Upgrade

Tags: tabular, ssas-tabular, sql-server-2022

I have an old SSAS Tabular model (Compatibility Level = 1103) in a Visual Studio SSAS Project

[image]

Recently the client created a new SQL Server running SQL 2022. I want to upgrade and deploy the current Tabular Model to be able to run on the new server.

The BIM code is still in XML and I know that it needs to be in JSON.

How would one go about to upgrade the model to be deployable to the new SQL Server?

Comment: BIM Code xml deployment should still work it has not been deprecated, change the compatibility level in your model and deploy it. Do you have a link for your source says it is json only?